# SQL syntax error in two selects join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a left join with another select but I keep getting a syntax error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT prediction_id, sum(value) from expenses as valoarea GROUP BY p' at line 3

```
SELECT id, name FROM `predictions` 
where `predictions` .tablet_id in (select id from tablets where user_id = 19)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT prediction_id, sum(value) from expenses as expense_value GROUP BY prediction_id) ex
ON `predictions`.id = `ex`.prediction_id;
```

Cand someone see what's wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

See the [syntax of a `SELECT` query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html): `JOIN` comes before `WHERE`:

```
SELECT id, name FROM `predictions` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT prediction_id, sum(value) from expenses as expense_value GROUP BY prediction_id) ex
ON `predictions`.id = `ex`.prediction_id;
where `predictions`.tablet_id in (select id from tablets where user_id = 19)
```